# Where is parameters property of LambdaInvokeProps?

Tags: typescript, aws-lambda, aws-cdk, aws-step-functions

I'm using CDK and Typescript to create a `StateMachine`. I need to set [parameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-inputpath-params.html) property on `LambdaInvoke` but it seems that `parameters` property is missing from `LambdaInvokeProps`.

It seems very strange to me, because all usual properties such as `imputPath`, `resultPath`, `resultSelector`, etc, are there.

Is there a way to set `parameters` property?

Using `aws-cdk-lib` 2.28.1

Comment: The CDK `LambdaInvoke` construct abstracts away the task `Parameters` from the caller.  Are you looking for [payload](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_stepfunctions_tasks.LambdaInvoke.html#payload)?

Comment: @fedonev. Thank you, that is exactly what I was looking for. If you make your comment an answer I will mark it as the accepted answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `aws_stepfunctions_tasks.LambdaInvoke` construct abstracts away the task `Parameters` from the caller.

Pass the event input to the Lambda using the `LambdaInvoke` [payload](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_stepfunctions_tasks.LambdaInvoke.html#payload) prop.

N.B. the construct is the CDK implementation of the [Optimised Integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-lambda.html) for Lambda.